# Firefox view responsive layout doesn't work

Tags: responsive-design

I am working on a responsive layout locally. I am testing with firefox responsive layout tool. For some reason Firefox is not applying the media query for 320px. I tried this solution [Browser not recognizing max-device-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215987/browser-not-recognizing-max-device-width#) but it didn't work.
Any idea?

My code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
.btn-default {
    display: inline-block !important;
 }
.slide figure figcaption {
    right: 21%;
    width: 67%;
}

 aside {
    width: 64%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 30%;
}


 .footerFloat {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 118px;
}
 .textul {

text-align: left;

 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align:left;
  margin: -36px 0px 16px;
   }
   }
```

When I debug my code with inspect element at 320px resolution it doesn't read the above code. Intsead goes to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
.btn-default {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }


aside {
    width: 64%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 30%;
}

header {
    background-position: center; 
    background-image: url('Images/logo_mobile.png') ;
}
 h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align:center;
  margin: -136px 0px 16px;
 }

.textul {

text-align: left;

}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Also note that Firefox includes the vertical scrollbar in device width.

Comment: Create: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)